# How to add the result of one query to the other query (no join columns, not same amount of colmns)

Tags: sql

I have a query that just generates 1 column with 1 result.

```
Select SUM(PAYMENT) from table 1
```

I have a query that generates 3 columns with 1 row result.

```
Select 
sum(SALE),
FirstDate (using over partition),
LastDate (using over partition)
from
    select 
        sale,
        dt_transaction
    from
        table 2
```

How can I simple add the column of query 1 to the output of query 2? 
I cannot join, nor can I do a union all (unless I add null columns?). 
Is there another, easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a column to query that gets the three column result set like so:

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3, (select count(*) from table) as additional_column
from three_col_table
```

Comment: Thanks for ur fast reply! So basically it would be like Select 
sum(SALE) AS AMT_SALE,
FirstDate (using over partition),
LastDate (using over partition),
(Select SUM(PAYMENT) from table 1) as AMT_PAYMENT
from
    select 
        sale,
        dt_transaction
    from
        table 2

Comment: Yep. Also just an FYI this sub-query to get the sum will be executed for every row. Depending on your result set that might be bit of a performance hit.

Comment: The result will always be 1 row because all the sales and counts are aggregated so I think it should be fine. Thanks ! :D